# How to install glibc for Mac OS?

Tags: macos, glibc

I know that glibc has not been ported to Mac OS X. But is there a way for me to install glibc in Mac. glibc has some shared objects which I need for installing my rpm package.

Answer (score 8):

> But is there a way for me to install glibc in Mac.

**No** (that's what "has not been ported" *means*).