# How to install glibc on BigSur

Tags: macos, homebrew, glibc, macos-big-sur

```
$ brew install glibc
glibc: Linux is required for this software.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

what is going on?

I know there is another question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178248/how-to-install-glibc-for-mac-os), which says that it has not been ported, however I guess that state has changed because there are a couple of places around (including home brew page) saying that it should work.

I'm on BigSur / Intel based MBP

Answer (score 1):

> including home brew page

If you mean [this page](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula-linux/glibc), note that it's under *linux* subdirectory.

The GLIBC *currently* [will fail](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=configure.ac;h=f2588f394f288a6cabf60daf1c376ae320c7d0e7;hb=HEAD#l524) to `configure` on anything other than `*-linux*` or `*-gnu*`.

Comment: Note that there is an undocumented `--enable-hacker-mode` option shown in that source which will skip the check.