# Error "fatal error: 'sys/sysmacros.h' file not found"

Tags: macos, clang, macos-big-sur

I have a compilation error on [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) with the standard [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) compiler (version 13.0.0).

I am trying to include the sys/sysmacros.h to use the makedev() function which surprisingly [is mentioned](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1547212-makedev) on the Apple developer website and should be compatible with macOS 15.5+.

Including *sys/types.h* also gives me an error, however *sys/stat.h* works. Sadly it still doesn't give me the makedev(), major() and minor() functions that I need.

The Linux manual page of [makedev](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/major.3.html#top_of_page) states there were some changes in the glibc library, but as far as I know, macOS does not use the glibc library.

There should be a simple way of installing glibc on macOS using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (`brew`) as described [here](https://brewinstall.org/install-glibc-on-mac-with-brew/), but I get the same error as was mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918855/how-to-install-glibc-on-bigsur). So apparently currently there is no proper way of doing it and then I am not sure if this will solve my problem.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What is your question? Do you wish to resolve the error in the title or install glibc?

Comment: I would like to resolve the error in the title. Installing glibc would just be an attempt in doing that

Comment: You have resolved it by `#include <sys/stat.h>`, have not you?

Comment: Nope, I haven't resolved the issue. Thank you for pointing it out though, I have edited the question so it's more clear ;)

Comment: GLIBC doesn't support MacOS, and is _irrelevant_ to your question.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Why have you removed the tag C?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `makedev` is defined in *sys/types.h*. Just add `#include <sys/types.h>` into your files. *sys/types.h* is a header file of Kernel.framework. You should set it in the Clang invocation, like `clang -framework Kernel ...`.

You can also define these macros as they are defined in *sys/types.h*:

```c
#define major(x)        ((int32_t)(((u_int32_t)(x) >> 24) & 0xff))
#define minor(x)        ((int32_t)((x) & 0xffffff))
#define makedev(x, y)    ((dev_t)(((x) << 24) | (y)))
```

Comment: Thank you, adding `#include <sys/types.h> ` and then setting it in clang invocation like you described helped